# mysql update- nested where search offered

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i try to update a single column: address should be filled with a value when several variables are the same(subids) and address is NULL.
I always got error: #1054 - Unknown column 'rfri_acymailing_listsub.listid' in 'where clause', but this columns exist, i can search for the fields.

The code:

```
UPDATE rfri_acymailing_subscriber 
SET
rfri_acymailing_subscriber.address = 'Dear Management'
WHERE 
rfri_acymailing_listsub.listid = rfri_acymailing_list.listid
AND rfri_acymailing_subscriber.subid = rfri_acymailing_listsub.subid
AND rfri_acymailing_list.name LIKE  'EN%'
AND rfri_acymailing_subscriber.address IS NULL 

(SELECT FROM   rfri_acymailing_subscriber, rfri_acymailing_listsub, rfri_acymailing_list );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the tables you're joining with after the `UPDATE` clause, not at the end of the query:

```
UPDATE rfri_acymailing_subscriber AS s
JOIN rfri_acymailing_listsub AS ls ON ls.subid = s.subid
JOIN rfri_acymailing_list AS l ON LS.listid = l.listid
SET s.address = 'Dear Management'
WHERE l.name LIKE 'EN%'
AND s.address IS NULL
```